# Inconsistent positioning of subscripts with STIX2Math

Tags: unicode-math, stix

Using STIX2Math via XeLaTeX, the positioning of subscripts in inline math is different depending on whether said inline math appears in the main text or, for instance, in a footnote. The following TeX document illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}
% \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}
$P_\varphi$ is the canonical angular momentum.\footnote{$P_\varphi$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, if I `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}` instead, I get

[image]

which seems fine (or at least consistent).

I'm using an up to date TeX Live distribution on macOS 10.13 (High Sierra).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with a slightly out-of-date TeX Live 2015 - both subscripts look like your footnote (i.e., not nicely kerned).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the fact that in the `\footnotesize` part the “P” is typeset with the font having the `+ssty0` or `+ssty1` feature enabled.

If I disable the `script-features`, the kerning is correct (but the smaller optical size fonts are not chosen).

Consider this test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  version=noscript,
  script-features={},
]

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{With script features}
$P_\varphi$ is the canonical angular momentum.

\medskip

{\footnotesize
$P_\varphi$ is the canonical angular momentum.\par}


\subsubsection*{Without script features}
\mathversion{noscript}
$P_\varphi$ is the canonical angular momentum.

\medskip

{\footnotesize
$P_\varphi$ is the canonical angular momentum.\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe that the smaller optical font in the STiX Two family need a thorough reworking.